# Maximum number of users connected to a shared folder

Tags: hard-drive

I was wondering… If I have a WD 7200rpm HDD with 1 TB, and one shared folder, what is the maximum users who can connect to it, browse directories, and copy small amounts of files without slow access?

Generally speaking, is there any formula to calculate the optimum number of users with access on a single drive, or some link, etc… ?

I don't need an answer regarding network bandwith or OS limitations, just for HDDs.

Answer (score 0):

No real limitation. If the computer has sufficient RAM, it will hold the necessary data structures in memory. And memory is fast enough to keep up with the network.

That said, you'll have issues with > 100 writes/second. Eventually they'll have to go to disk, and a 7200 RPM spinning disk has a certain latency (has to wait for the right sector to pass the write head).